# How to pause an android app when a dialog box is being displayed?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener

Hey I'm making a android app that is a simple webview. I want to redirect the user to browser on certain urls. I want to display a message in the form of a dialog box to alert the user that they are being redirected to their browser. The user will click OK and then the user is redirected.

The following code is what I have. The problem is the app continues with the redirection without waiting for the user to click OK on the dialog box. I want to app to pause and continue any activity only if the user clicks OK.

```
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { /*DialogInterface called while setting the AlertDialog Buttons */


                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    //Here you can perform functions of Alert Dialog Buttons as shown
                    switch (which){
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:

                            //I want the app to pause here.
                            //MainActivity.this.onPause(); does not work
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Title");// Set the Title of Alert Dialog
            builder.setMessage("We are taking you to the admin page.").setPositiveButton("OK",dialogClickListener).show();
```

Thanks, i prefer not using a wait() since I want my user to acknowledge what is happening by clicking a button

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {

    private boolean mustScan = true;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        if (mustScan) {
            // Just scan
            // Note: If you use a Thread with a while loop, use this:
            // while (true) {if (mustScan) {} }
        }
    }

    // This is the method you use to show the Dialog
    private void showResults (SomeResults here) {
        // Show the dialog
        // ...
        mustScan = false;
        // Also, in the OnClickListener of the buttons add "mustScan = true;"
    }
```